# False - Dead Code, OK. But nothing for True, why?

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement

Consider the following code:

```
    if (true) {
        System.out.println("True");
    }

    if (false) {
        System.out.println("False");
    }
```

You are using Eclipse IDE.

You'll get `Dead Code` warning in Eclipse IDE for above `false` block.

But why there is no warning message for `true` block, even though the condition is unnecessary in this case?

The question may sound silly. But it seemed like an valid question. Any thoughts?

Comment: From a language perspective, there's nothing *wrong* with it - the code can still be executed and isn't dead. From a practical perspective, it's not uncommon during debugging to replace some complicated expression with `if (true)`, so it's convenient that it doesn't do this.

Comment: Um... because it's executed code?

Comment: `if(true)` is sometimes used to prematurely end a method without creating unreachable code, for debugging purposes.

Comment: @ChrisHayes: Even with if(false) Java will not throw error/exception, only eclipse shows a warning. Why it isn't the same with if(true)?

Comment: @GokulNath Because the people who wrote that part of Eclipse decided it wasn't necessary to show a warning? Hell, there might even be an Eclipse setting to warn in that scenario that you just don't have enabled.

Comment: Some developers love to user the while(true) {... break;} statements. I Guess this is similar.

Comment: @Tsikon No, it's not similar in the least.

Comment: Well, if you want a statement to be executed for whatever reasons you have it seems like a solution for you. Personally, I don't use the while(true) {} statements, there is always a way to avoid that. And @GokulNath please take the time to accept the answer if you find it satisfying.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably an opinion-based question, but what the heck, I'll throw in my opinion.

If someone types `if (true)`, then either they know what they're doing, are just experimenting, or are hopeless.  It's not likely for this to be a mistake.  It would take special logic for Eclipse to catch this, and it doesn't seem worthwhile.

You could say the same about `if (false)`--that Eclipse shouldn't warn about that because someone who types it in must know what they're doing.  However, Eclipse already has logic to catch dead code in other situations besides this one, and it might take special logic **not** to display a warning in that case.  Which is doable, but probably not worth the effort, since warnings aren't really a problem.  (I sometimes use `if(false)` to temporarily disable a section of code, and this causes Eclipse to display yellow lines on the screen.  Big deal.)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you would expect that statements written by you are executed. For dead code your expectation can not be achieved, thus you get a warning. But for the if-case your expectation is always achieved.

Answer (score 0):

`if (false) { ... }` is a dead code, because it will never get executed in the program.
Whereas `if (true) { ... }` gets executed, no matter what.!

Its the same case with loop statements.

`while (true) { ... }` results in an infinite loop. Normally we put `System.exit(0);` in this case to terminate the loop or `break;` to come out of the loop.

`while (false) { ... }` never gets executed.